# How to write an if statement that stops code when any variable in a vector is outside of the limits provided?

Tags: r, if-statement

How do I write an if statement that stops code when any variable in the vector is outside of the intended sequence?

```
y <- c(1,2,3,4,11)

if(y > 10 | y < 0) 
    stop("Score has to be between 0 and 10")
```

Would it be done through loops? If so, which loop?

Comment: See `help("any")`

Comment: `if/else` is not vectorized

Comment: @akrun That's why they need `any()`, i.e. `any(y > 10 | y < 0)`

Comment: @duckmayr Thank you so much! I cannot believe I've never seen the any() function before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
if(!all(between(y, 0, 10)) )
```

Or with `stopifnot`

```
stopifnot(all(y %in% 1:9))
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `stopifnot(all(between(y, 0, 10)))` which has the advantage of addressing non-integers.

Comment: @ChuckP `between` returns a logical vector for any value between the 0 and 10 including floats. i.e. `v1 <- c(1.2, 3.1, 4.2, 10.2); between(v1, 0, 10)`

Comment: I understand that I meant `if(!all(between(y, 0, 10))` fails for me, it's at least missing a parens but that doesn't fix it whereas `stopifnot(all(between(y, 0, 10)))` does what you want with non integer checking as well

Comment: @ChuckP thanks you are right.  I was using two versions incase the OP wanted either one.  Here, the example showed integers, so I didn't change in the second case